# Branding SharePoint Search Result

Tags: sharepoint, search, formatting, coding-style, richtextbox

In my SharePoint site I have a list wich has a column that contains rich text in it. (i.e text with bold, color and italic style).

Now when user perform search, If the search key word match with the data in rich text column it will show that record as a search result which is perfect.

But the result in search result page show that text in plain format and my requirement is to show that result along with its formating i.e with bold and italic style.

Can any one tell me how to achieve this...!

Thanks

Sachin !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement custom search result page. Example [here](http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=27&skatID=227&artID=6148).